# Object Oriented Tkinter - Centering Multiple Frames

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm writing an object oriented program in  Python and using Tkinter to build up a GUI. I'm new to object oriented and Tkinter so I've been using Sentdex videos on youtube, effbot.org, stackoverflow and zetcode.com to help me.

This is my program, I've stripped it down a lot so that its shorter and easier to understand. It starts off in full screen mode and centres the frame. I then click the login button and the next frame is raised, this one however is not centred despite it being in the middle of a grid surrounded by cells with weight=1.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Program(tk.Tk):        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):   
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        frame = Login(container, self)
        self.frames[Login] = frame

        frame.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")

        for F in (Login, AdminHome):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(Login)

    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class Login(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        name = tk.Label(self, text = "Program")
        name.grid(row=0, columnspan=5, sticky="W"+"E")

        username = tk.Label(self, text="Username: ")
        username.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="W")

        user = ttk.Entry(self, text ="", width=45)
        user.grid(row=1, column=2 ,columnspan=3, sticky="w")

        password = tk.Label(self, text="Password: ")
        password.grid(row=2, columnspan=2, sticky="W")

        passentry = ttk.Entry(self, text ="", width=45)
        passentry.grid(row=2, column=2 ,columnspan=3, sticky="W")

        loginb = ttk.Button(self, text = "Login", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(AdminHome))
        loginb.grid(row=3, columnspan=5, sticky="W"+"E")

class AdminHome(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        name = tk.Label(self, text = "Admin Home")
        name.grid(row=0, sticky="W")

        name = tk.Label(self, text = "FirstName + LastName")
        name.grid(row=0, column=5 ,sticky="E")

        update = ttk.Button(self, text = "Update Online", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(AdminHome))
        update.grid(row=1, columnspan=6, sticky="W"+"E")

        fetch = ttk.Button(self, text = "Fetch Data", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(AdminHome))
        fetch.grid(row=2, columnspan=6, sticky="W"+"E")

        a = ttk.Button(self, text = "a", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(AdminHome))
        a.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, sticky="W"+"E")

        b = ttk.Button(self, text = "b", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(AdminHome))
        b.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky="W"+"E")

        c = ttk.Button(self, text = "c", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(AdminHome))
        c.grid(row=3, column=4, columnspan=2, sticky="W"+"E")

        edit = ttk.Button(self, text = "Edit Details", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(AdminHome))
        edit.grid(row=4, columnspan=6, sticky="W"+"E")

app = Program()
app.state('zoomed')
app.mainloop()
```

[Login Screen before progress bars are added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvDiI.png)

When I add the following code to the AdminHome class, the problem is reversed, the login screen stops being centred but the admin home screen becomes centred.

```
    uip = tk.Label(self, text="Updating in Progress ")
    uip.grid(row=5, sticky="W")

    updatebar = ttk.Progressbar(self,orient ="horizontal",length = 200, mode ="determinate")
    updatebar.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky="W"+"E")
    updatebar["maximum"] = 100
    updatebar["value"] = 50


    fip = tk.Label(self, text="Fetching in Progress ")
    fip.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky="W")

    fetchbar = ttk.Progressbar(self,orient ="horizontal",length = 200, mode ="determinate")
    fetchbar.grid(row=5, column=3, sticky="W"+"E")
    fetchbar["maximum"] = 100
    fetchbar["value"] = 50
```

[Login Screen after progress bars are added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpyqO.png)

Can someone tell me why this happens and how I can fix it. I need the solution to also work if I change the size of the widgets in these frames and with all other frames that I add to the program.

Comment: You are creating the `Login` frame twice. Is that intentional?

Comment: No, it's not intentional, how would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't that the frame isn't centered in the container, it's that the admin page widgets aren't centered in the admin frame. You can see this pretty easily by giving the `AdminHome` frame a distinctive color. When you do this, you'll see that the `AdminHome` frame remains centered in the window.

The code that you've copied was specifically designed for the individual "page" objects fill the cell that they are in. The code only works that way since the widgets are all stacked on top of each other. They need to be the same size or you will see the larger frames behind the smaller ones.

Since you don't quite understand how the code works, my advice is to not try to change it. Instead of trying to make the pages centered, focus on making the data *in* the pages centered. Each page was designed to be completely separate, so whatever you do inside that frame won't affect any other widgets.

The simplest solution to having the content in each page centered is to use another frame. Put all the widgets in that frame, and then center that frame. You don't really need to do that, you can also use the same trick you tried to employ earlier, by adding "weighted" rows and columns surrounding all the widgets inside the page.

Following is a complete working example. It's not the only way to solve the problem, and may not even be the best way. Note that because of the use of `place`, you *must* give the overall window a size (or set the `zoomed` attribute like you're doing). This is because the use of `place` doesn't force a window to fit its contents.

The important thing to look for is the use of `innerFrame` inside each page. This is the thing that is centered.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Program(tk.Tk):        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):   
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (Login, AdminHome):

            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(Login)

    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class Login(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        innerFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        innerFrame.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")

        name = tk.Label(innerFrame, text = "Program")
        name.grid(row=0, columnspan=5, sticky="W"+"E")

        username = tk.Label(innerFrame, text="Username: ")
        username.grid(row=1, columnspan=2, sticky="W")

        user = ttk.Entry(innerFrame, text ="", width=45)
        user.grid(row=1, column=2 ,columnspan=3, sticky="w")

        password = tk.Label(innerFrame, text="Password: ")
        password.grid(row=2, columnspan=2, sticky="W")

        passentry = ttk.Entry(innerFrame, text ="", width=45)
        passentry.grid(row=2, column=2 ,columnspan=3, sticky="W")

        loginb = ttk.Button(innerFrame, text = "Login", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(AdminHome))
        loginb.grid(row=3, columnspan=5, sticky="W"+"E")

class AdminHome(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        innerFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        innerFrame.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor="c")

        name = tk.Label(innerFrame, text = "Admin Home")
        name.grid(row=0, sticky="W")

        name = tk.Label(innerFrame, text = "FirstName + LastName")
        name.grid(row=0, column=5 ,sticky="E")

        update = ttk.Button(innerFrame, text = "Update Online", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(AdminHome))
        update.grid(row=1, columnspan=6, sticky="W"+"E")

        fetch = ttk.Button(innerFrame, text = "Fetch Data", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(AdminHome))
        fetch.grid(row=2, columnspan=6, sticky="W"+"E")

        a = ttk.Button(innerFrame, text = "a", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(AdminHome))
        a.grid(row=3, columnspan=2, sticky="W"+"E")

        b = ttk.Button(innerFrame, text = "b", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(AdminHome))
        b.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=2, sticky="W"+"E")

        c = ttk.Button(innerFrame, text = "c", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(AdminHome))
        c.grid(row=3, column=4, columnspan=2, sticky="W"+"E")

        edit = ttk.Button(innerFrame, text = "Edit Details", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(AdminHome))
        edit.grid(row=4, columnspan=6, sticky="W"+"E")

app = Program()
app.state('zoomed')
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I tried using this solution but without column weights, you can see the frames underneath the one currently raised, is there a way to overcome this? If not, why is there extra space in the AdminHome frame when grid is used and how would I remdedy the problem using grid?

Comment: "this solution but without column weights" - I don't know what that means. What is "this solution"?  Yes, of course there are solutions. Your question is a bit unclear at this point. We've established that the inner frame is properly centered, so are you asking how to center the things inside the admin frame? Or are you asking about the progress bar on the login screen?

Comment: So I've used place and 'relx' and 'rely' with values set to 0.5 as you suggested but what happens is you can see the AdminHome frame below the raised Login frame. My question is, how would I prevent any frame that is not raised from being seen? and if there isn't a way of doing this, How can I center the things in the AdminHome frame and Login frame while using grid?